# Forcing Stanford NLP's WordsToSentencesAnnotator to split sentences on dots

Tags: regex, nlp, stanford-nlp

**Question**:

How to force Stanford NLP's WordsToSentencesAnnotator to split sentences on dots? I tried adding `-ssplit.boundaryMultiTokenRegex "//."`, but it still fails to split on the `.` all the time.

I use [Stanford CoreNLP version 3.5.2 (2015-04-20)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with Java 1.8.0_25 x64.

---

**Example**:

I have a text that contains two sentences: `D R E L I N. Okay.`

I use Stanford NLP's WordsToSentencesAnnotator to split the text into sentences through the command line interface:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP 
             -annotators tokenize,ssplit  -file test.txt
```

It returns just one sentence `D R E L I N. Okay.` instead of  two sentences `['D R E L I N.',  'Okay.']`, .i.e. looking at the output XML file, the node `sentences` had only one `sentence` child:

[image]

Comment: Just a guess — try escaping with backslashes rather than forward slashes?

Comment: @JonGauthier I'll try.